# What is the alternative of Signalr for a server side communication with web socket in C# .Net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, websocket, signalr

I have implemented signalr Hub as a server implementation in .net core c# with Client as angular js web app. However  some time when I open angular app multiple browser tabs and send a message from .net core logic, some of the tabs are getting my messages and some are not getting my message.  Below is my question posted already in the community.

[Signalr Web socket communication in .Net core is broadcasting messages to only few web socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71606707/signalr-web-socket-communication-in-net-core-is-broadcasting-messages-to-only-f)

is there solution for above issue? or any other alternative like socket.io etc I can try? Also please provide the implementation for other alternative way

Comment: [WebSockets support in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-6.0#send-and-receive-messages)

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is so it's hard to recommend a solution. Can you reproduce it on all machines, how many tabs are open, is it in all browsers? You'd need to spend some time debugging to better understand what the actual problem is, or to at  least narrow it down a bit so people like me can help troubleshoot.